# LaTeX package stmaryrd doesn't work together with org-mode beamer template

Tags: org-mode

[This page](http://orgmode.org/worg/exporters/beamer/tutorial.html) gives some templates to let you make beamer presentations in org-mode. But if I use some symbols from the `stmaryrd` package, they won't get rendered if I export to pdf using org-mode.

The following is the templates from 2.1 (Beamer specific settings) and 2.2 (Outline levels for frames (slides)) of that page at the time of writing, importing the `stmaryrd` package (`#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{stmaryrd}`), some sample text and a formula using some `stmaryrd` symbols (`llbracket`, `\rrbracket`).

```
#+TITLE:     Writing Beamer presentations in org-mode
#+AUTHOR:    Eric S Fraga
#+EMAIL:     e.fraga@ucl.ac.uk
#+DATE:      2010-03-30 Tue
#+DESCRIPTION: 
#+KEYWORDS: 
#+LANGUAGE:  en

#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{stmaryrd}

#+OPTIONS:   H:3 num:t toc:t \n:nil @:t ::t |:t ^:t -:t f:t *:t <:t
#+OPTIONS:   TeX:t LaTeX:t skip:nil d:nil todo:t pri:nil tags:not-in-toc
#+INFOJS_OPT: view:nil toc:nil ltoc:t mouse:underline buttons:0 path:http://orgmode.org/org-info.js
#+EXPORT_SELECT_TAGS: export
#+EXPORT_EXCLUDE_TAGS: noexport
#+LINK_UP:   
#+LINK_HOME:

#+startup: beamer
#+LaTeX_CLASS: beamer
#+LaTeX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [bigger]

* Introduction

Some text here

A formula:

\[ \llbracket 234 \rrbracket \]
```

Exporting this to a pdf file doesn't work, in the sense that the symbols `\llbracket` and `\rrbracket` won't be rendered. The same goes for exporting to a tex file, and then using `pdflatex` to compile the tex file to pdf; this is one of the error messages I get:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
.73 \[ \llbracket
               234 \rrbracket \]
```

But if this line in the org-file is commented out:

```
#+LaTeX_CLASS: beamer
```

The symbols are rendered. But then the pdf file doesn't look like a beamer presentation any more (which is not a surprise). Similarly, if I export to tex, and then comment out this line in the tex file:

```
\mode<{{{beamermode}}}>
```

The symbols are rendered correctly. I get a lot of errors when compiling the tex file, and the resulting pdf is not that nice, but at least the symbols are rendered.

([Link to tex output from exporting from org-mode](http://pastebin.com/kEMvV17y))

**Does the stmaryrd package work in a non-beamer org file?** Yes; the following document can be compiled to pdf correctly:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{stmaryrd}

This is rendered: \llbracket
```

**.emacs setup:** This is the setup for beamer that I am using in my `.emacs` file. It was taken from [this blog post](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.no/2009/10/writing-presentations-with-org-mode-and.html). The code adds the beamer class to the `org-latex-classes` variable.

```
(add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
;; beamer class, for presentations
'("beamer"
   "\\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}\n
    \\mode<{{{beamermode}}}>\n
    \\usetheme{{{{beamertheme}}}}\n
    \\usecolortheme{{{{beamercolortheme}}}}\n
    \\beamertemplateballitem\n
    \\setbeameroption{show notes}
    \\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\n
    \\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\n
    \\usepackage{hyperref}\n
    \\usepackage{color}
    \\usepackage{listings}
    \\lstset{numbers=none,language=[ISO]C++,tabsize=4,
frame=single,
basicstyle=\\small,
showspaces=false,showstringspaces=false,
showtabs=false,
keywordstyle=\\color{blue}\\bfseries,
commentstyle=\\color{red},
}\n
    \\usepackage{verbatim}\n
    \\institute{{{{beamerinstitute}}}}\n          
      \\subject{{{{beamersubject}}}}\n"

   ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")

   ("\\begin{frame}[fragile]\\frametitle{%s}"
     "\\end{frame}"
     "\\begin{frame}[fragile]\\frametitle{%s}"
     "\\end{frame}")))
```

Comment: I had never used `org-mode`. But there are serious problems in your `.tex`. (I) You should *fill in the blanks* in `\mode<{{{beamermode}}}>`,  `\usetheme{{{{beamertheme}}}}` and `\usecolortheme{{{{beamercolortheme}}}}`. And (II) presentation materials should be placed in `frame` environment. Without `frame` it does look weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my `.emacs` beamer setup code, I replaced the code described in the question with the following code, as found [on this webpage](http://orgmode.org/worg/exporters/beamer/ox-beamer.html) at the time of writing.

```
(require 'ox-latex)
(add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
             '("beamer"
               "\\documentclass\[presentation\]\{beamer\}"
               ("\\section\{%s\}" . "\\section*\{%s\}")
               ("\\subsection\{%s\}" . "\\subsection*\{%s\}")
               ("\\subsubsection\{%s\}" . "\\subsubsection*\{%s\}")))
```

The aforementioned website seems more up-to-date than the blog post that I was initially using. From what I've found, it seems to be *the* way to set up Beamer for org-mode, right now.

As for the template for the beamer presentation, I used the interactive function `org-beamer-insert-options-template`, choosing the "global" option, to generate a template.

Now, using the `stmaryrd` package in a beamer presentation works fine:

```
...
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{stmaryrd}

This is rendered: \llbracket
...
```